# Transform CRS of Shapefile in R

Tags: coordinate-system, r, sf

I started with an AutoCAD DWG file and used FME Workbench to extract elevation data into a shapefile.

`read_sf` yields:

```
> shapename
Simple feature collection with 41620 features and 1 field (with 757 geometries empty)
geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
dimension:      XYZ
bbox:           xmin: 313368.6 ymin: 4832795 xmax: 314211.3 ymax: 4833629
epsg (SRID):    4267
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +ellps=clrk66 +no_defs
# A tibble: 41,620 x 2
   Massing_ID                                                                                geometry
        <int>                                                                      <MULTIPOLYGON [°]>
 1         NA Z (((313962.3 4832886 6.7, 314004.9 4832898 6.7, 314000.5 4832913 6.7, 313962.3 4832...
 2         NA Z (((313974.8 4832889 11.58, 313973.6 4832894 11.58, 313966.3 4832892 11.58, 313974....
 3         NA Z (((313975.1 4832904 11.58, 313976.1 4832901 11.58, 313964.6 4832898 11.58, 313975....
```

Trying `shp_crs <- st_transform(shapename, crs=4326)` yields:

```
> shp_crs
Simple feature collection with 41620 features and 1 field (with 757 geometries empty)
geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
dimension:      XYZ
bbox:           xmin: 313368.6 ymin: 4832795 xmax: 314211.3 ymax: 4833629
epsg (SRID):    4326
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
# A tibble: 41,620 x 2
   Massing_ID                                                                                geometry
        <int>                                                                      <MULTIPOLYGON [°]>
 1         NA Z (((313962.3 4832886 6.7, 314004.9 4832898 6.7, 314000.5 4832913 6.7, 313962.3 4832...
 2         NA Z (((313974.8 4832889 11.58, 313973.6 4832894 11.58, 313966.3 4832892 11.58, 313974....
 3         NA Z (((313975.1 4832904 11.58, 313976.1 4832901 11.58, 313964.6 4832898 11.58, 313975....
```

The data is unchanged. Only proj4string has changed. Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If these values:

```
bbox:           xmin: 313368.6 ymin: 4832795 xmax: 314211.3 ymax: 4833629
```

(which are the range of the data location values) are latitude-longitude:

```
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +ellps=clrk66 +no_defs
```

then something is terribly wrong with the shape of the earth.

Lat-long coordinates should only ever be (-180,180),(-90,90) - your coordinates are clearly not in that range and so the transformation code just shrugs and returns the same numbers. Its a "Garbage-in, Garbage-out" philosophy. Possibly an error message would be better, but the mistake was made previous to this.

Your data is more likely in a projected coordinate system, and might be in metres, like a UTM zone. Less likely its degrees multiplied by 10,000 for some reason.